# Why is MyCrypto is disabling the Sign Transaction button?

Tags: contract-invocation, gas-price, gas-limit, gas-estimate, mycrypto

I'm using MyCrypto to execute a function of a smart contract but the sign Transaction button is disabled. I'm using the setting to auto calculate the Gas Limit and its suggesting a limit of **68908** with a Gas price of **20 gwei**:

`20000000000 * 68908 = 0.001378 ETH ~= $2.86 USD`

However it won't let me sign the contract as the button is disabled, if I override the automatic calculation and lower the gas limit or gas price so the total is under 0.0007 ETH then the button re-enables, but this is not a high enough value for the transaction to be accepted.

Why is MyCrypto disabling the Sign Transaction button depending on the Gas value and is there a work around?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My guess is that when they simulate the execution it fails. Perhaps there isn't enough ether to pay the resulting transaction, or the execution fails for some reason (a contract could revert if the gas price isn't a value expected).

Comment: The contract has 1 ETH and I'm trying to use the execute to move 0.1 ETH (10000000000000000 GWEI) to a new ETH address that I hold so there should be no issue with insufficient funds in the contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was unaware that when executing the contract, I could not use the funds within the contract to pay for the transaction.

The contract was created from the original ETH address and this original ETH address only had around 0.0007 ETH which was insufficient to pay for the transaction. I moved in more funds to the original address which, when they land, should allow me to execute the contract.

I'm not clear on whether I could have just executed the contract using a completely different ETH address to fund the transaction instead? I couldn't see a way to do this using the MyCrypto app. I know the contract has a concept of owners and I suspect only they would be allowed to execute it so perhaps this wouldn't have worked.